# Unity FixedUpdate vs Update physics on input

Tags: unity-game-engine

In multiple answers it was stated that `Update` is called once every frame and shouldn't be used for physics update, it should however be used for input or you might miss important events.
The problem that arises now is what if I ise `Update` to influence a physics object?
That for example on a mouse release, some balls start moving and spinning.

```
void Update
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
       ball.getComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(vector);
       ball.getComponent<Rigidbody>().AddTorque(vector2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve optimal performance you should split the code.

- Inside [Update](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/update) you get the input and store it somewhere.
- Inside [FixedUpdate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) you calculate physics.

In the specific case you mentioned the code will become:

```
bool mouseUp = false;

void Update()
{
    mouseUp = Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0);
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (mouseUp)
    {
       ball.getComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(vector);
       ball.getComponent<Rigidbody>().AddTorque(vector2);
       mouseUp = false;
    }
}
```

*-------------

EDIT (after derHugo and Wouter Vandenputte comments)*

In some cases [FixedUpdate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) might be called multiple times a frame. So it is safer to reset the value after it's usage. In the example case by adding `mouseUp = false`.

Comment: Then you should probably reset `mouseDown` after used once ... also a funny name for actually handling a `GetMouseButtonUp` event ^^

Comment: It is calculated in Update loop. So it always resets automatically at each Update.We could have issues only if we have `FixedUpdate` loop quicker than `Update` loop, that should be avoided anyway.

Comment: You mean the other way round ... usually `Update` is always faster then `FixedUpdate`. That's right but I would go for sure

Comment: Yes, exactly. We calculate `mouseUp` (previously `mouseDown`) in `Update` loop that is faster than `FixedUpdate`. (I was editing my comment...) So basically the mouseUp doesn't need any further reset. But yea, why not adding it anyway.

Comment: FixedUpdate can be called more than once a frame so without reseting, it could be run twice right?

Comment: [FixedUpdate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) could run twice a frame depending on target frame rate. You may reset the value after use in fixed update to be safer. (also updated the answer).